# Why do cells with the same date have different date serial numbers?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working with a workbook that has dates with time included in 2 worksheets. When a variable is set to the date in worksheet A, it'll look for it in worksheet B and retrieve the row number by using a second variable.

The issue I'm having is that when variable 1 and 2 match (i.e. the date exists in worksheet B), it doesn't recognize them as being equal. I stepped through the procedure to see if I could find out why they weren't matching and it turns out it's because the serial dates are slightly different.
44027.3333333325 and 44027.3333333333 for variable 1 and 2 respectively.

What do the last 2 numbers represent and how can I resolve this?

I've confirmed the cells have the same custom formatting and I have them "dimmed" as the same type (tried with both double and date). I need to keep the decimals for the time.

Thank you

Comment: Formatting does not change the underlying value and your dates have time components to them so they are not equal.

Comment: Right but if the time is the same in both dates, why wouldn't the serial date values be the same? for ex, the one I'm testing right now is 20/07/15 8:00:00 AM and vba's picking that up for both variables when I hover over them but the serial values are different.

Comment: The dates are saved as doubles and there is a large spread of decimal places that can be in the same second.  Excel will basically store up to `999` decimals of a second.  You will need to use rounding to make sure they are exact to the sub-second.

Comment: How are you reading these dates in VBA? Please show some code

Comment: Ah, that's what I'm trying to avoid, I need the row with the matching time. But what you're saying makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Scott Craner points out in the comments, the decimals represent the time down to a small fraction of second. To compare dates while ignoring the precise time, use the `DateValue` function; that way there is no need to apply rounding to your data.

```
Sub CompareTwoDates()

    Dim Date_1 As Date, Date_2 As Date

    Date_1 = 44027.3333333325
    Date_2 = 44027.3333333333
    
    If DateValue(Date_1) = DateValue(Date_2) Then
        MsgBox "The dates are identical.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Date Comparison"
    End If

End Sub
```

More on the `DateValue` function here: [DateValue function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datevalue-function)

Comment: I think @las wants to compare the time too, so I would add in `... + TimeValue(Date_1) ...` as well

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! I thought I'd already tried this before but I think I forgot to dim my variables as dates while trying datevalue with my new code.

Comment: @SuperSymmetry This actually captured the time when comparing them so i'm good, but thanks anyways!

Comment: Excellent! As @Super Symmetry says, use `TimeValue` if you need to include the time in the comparison. That will allow you to work with "normal" clock time (hours, minutes, and seconds) without needing to worry about microseconds.

Comment: @SuperSymmetry it wasn't an issue when I was testing one part of my code last week but I did end up needing TimeValue when I tested another date today so thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The decimal portion of the Excel datetime value represents the time. The 0.0000000008 difference between your two values represents around 10 micro seconds, which is more precision than Excel is able to display in a standard date/time format. If you are only interested in precision to a second level, you could safely round the values to six decimals, which will still give you a time with precision better than 1 second.